# AWS S3 sync how to exclude *.js files but include *.min.js?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a javascript folder called js/custom which has both *.js files and the minified version of the file with an extension called *.min.js, I want to make sure I only upload the minified version of the js file, how can I achieve this?

```
aws s3 sync /var/www/html/js/custom/* s3://inksedge/js/custom/*
--exclude 'js/custom/*.js'
```

above will exclude the minified version as well, how do i get the result i want?

Comment: Looking at the [cli docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#options), `--include` is described as "Don't exclude files or objects", so have you tried mixing your command with `--include **/*.min.js` ?

Comment: In fact it looks like the docs go into even more detail here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the --include argument to include the min files

--include

```
aws s3 sync /var/www/html/js/custom/* s3://inksedge/js/custom/*
--exclude 'js/custom/*.js' --include 'js/custom/*.min.js'
```